# Derivative d/dx of ||A*sigmoid(x)||^2,

Tags: derivatives, vectors, matrix-norms

Here ||A||^2 is the norm function which computes the sum of squares of all elements, x is a column vector.I have tried a lot of ways of computing it but none give me the correct answer. A is a matrix, the sigmoid function returns a list with the sigmoid of each element in the list.

Comment: Please define your quantities. I'm assuming $A$ is a matrix, but then how is sigmoid a vector? There is also not a standardized "the" sigmoid function, unless you mean the logistic one, even choosing that one then there is still not a standard way to get a vector output out of it.

Comment: I am sorry. the sigmoid function returns a  list with sigmoid of each element and A is a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the derivative of the sigmoid $\sigma(\chi)$ as 
$$\eqalign{
\sigma' = \frac{d\sigma}{d\chi} \\
}$$
When these scalar functions are applied *elementwise* on a vector $x$, they produce vector results 
$$s=\sigma(x),\qquad s'=\sigma'(x)$$
In such situations, it's usually more convenient to work with the differential quantity
$$\eqalign{
ds &= s'\odot dx \\
}$$
The $\odot$ symbol represents the elementwise/Hadamard product, but this can be eliminated in favor of multiplication by the diagonal matrix
$\;S' = {\rm Diag}(s')$ 
$$\eqalign{
ds &= S'\,dx \\
}$$
Now we're ready to calculate the requested gradient. 
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|As\|^2 \\&= As:As \\
d\phi &= 2As:A\,ds \\
 &= 2A^TAs:ds \\
 &= 2A^TAs:S'dx \\
 &= 2S'A^TAs:dx \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}
 &= 2S'A^TAs \\
\\
}$$

---

In some of the steps above, a colon is used to denote
the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{ A:B &= {\rm Tr}(A^TB) }$$
The cyclic property of the trace allows such products to be rearranged in a number of ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= A^T:B^T &= B:A \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C &= AC^T:B \\ 
}$$
**NB:** $\,$If your sigmoid function happens to be the logistic function, 
then there are nice formulas for the scalar derivative
$$\eqalign{
\sigma' &= \sigma - \sigma^2 \\
}$$
the vector differential
$$\eqalign{
ds &= \left(S-S^2\right)dx \qquad{\rm where}\;\; S = {\rm Diag}(s) \\
}$$
and the gradient
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} &= 2(S-S^2)A^TAs \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is constant,$$\partial_i(A\sigma(x))_j=A_{jk}\partial_i\sigma(x)_k=A_{jk}\delta_{ik}\sigma^\prime(x_i)=A_{ji}\sigma^\prime(x_i).$$So$$\partial_i\Vert A\sigma\Vert^2=2A_{jk}\sigma(x_k)A_{ji}\sigma^\prime(x_i)=2\sigma^TA^TA\sigma^\prime.$$

Answer (score 0):

What we have is the following

$$||\mathbf{A\sigma(x)}||^2 = \mathbf{\sigma^T(x)A^TA\sigma(x)}$$

Then we can use the following rule:

$$\mathbf{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^TAx} = \mathbf{x^T(A+A^T)}$$

in conjunction with the chain rule to get the following expression:

$$\mathbf{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}||A\sigma(x)||^2} = \mathbf{2\sigma^T(x)A^TA\cdot\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial x}}$$

However, given that $\sigma$ is a list of one variable inputs, the gradient of $\sigma$ should be a diagonal matrix.